# I want to check if time is between a period with PHP for Financial Markets

Tags: php

I need to check which financial markets are open but i didn't found api for it.
I want to make it with php, and i need to give for example 2 periods of time:

```
$open = 09:00:00; 
$close = 16:00:00;
```

and add a if statement as a checker if time is between those, and i will run a cron job for it.

All i want is to get the correct condition to check if time is on this period/frame.

Tried this but i dont know how to implement further:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('03:55:06');//start time
$datetime2 = new DateTime('11:55:06');//end time
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H hours %i minutes %s seconds');//
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider using the same zoned datetime for the financial market you are targeting.

For Paris as an example, you will use "Europe/Paris" to get the local datetime inside that timezone.

After that point, you can go further with your between condition. And the best way to get that is to use the `DateInterval` class, with its own `DateInterval::diff` method.

You can check out the official PHP documentation here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.dateinterval.php

And the `diff` method : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php

And I would compare the current zoned datetime to the start of the working interval : it must be equal or later.

I would compare it to the end of the working hours interval : it must be before or equal.

So you have everything you need to write it correctly now.

Comment: I'm converting every market time to Europe/Berlin than im defining for example, NYSE opens in 09:30 (New York Time), so in Europe/Berlin its 14:30, i just need the php script how do i make it because im not that good with PHP stuff that's the problem.